# GLSL When using an in variable the fragment shader causes an unexpected output

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader

I am busy implementing a deferred lighting system and have gotten all the way to having the bound position, diffuse and normal textures in my fragment shader in which I am to calculate the lighting specifications for each fragment.

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 fs_position;
in vec3 fs_color;
in vec4 fs_attenuation;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

uniform sampler2D diffuseSampler;
uniform sampler2D positionSampler;
uniform sampler2D normalSampler;

const float cutOffFactor = 200;
const float reflectivity = 0.15;
const float shineDamper = 1;


void main(void){
    vec2 frag = gl_PointCoord.xy;
    frag.x = (frag.x+1)/2f;
    frag.y = ((frag.y+1)/2f);


    vec4 texDiffuse = texture(diffuseSampler,frag);
    vec4 texPosition = texture(positionSampler,frag);
    vec4 texNormal = texture(normalSampler,frag);

    vec3 p = vec3(fs_position.xyz);
    vec3 ePosition = texPosition.xyz;
    ePosition = ePosition*200;
    vec3 eNormal = texNormal.xyz;
    vec3 unitNormal = normalize(eNormal);



    outColor = vec4(texNormal.xyz,1.0);
}
```

That is literally all that my Fragment Shader contains.
The probem lies at "vec3 p = vec3(fs_position.xyz);".
When I remove it the program renders a perfect normal map, but when I add it a blank screen in which I can rotate and eventually a certain color flickers.

fs_position has nothing to do with color and was inputted from the geometry shader (all references are correct) yet it somehow causes a massive malfunction.
Same thing happens as well with all in variables (fs_color and fs_attenuation).

Whats being rendered is a non-blended quad of equal per-vertex properties that covers the viewport that renders to a color_attachment that exists(as said without that line everything works).
(blending does nothing, and I will put additive blending on when I get a result worthy of allowing me to continue)

Any help will be appreciated, the engine and shaders have never acted this way for me before and no errors are popping up.

Extra code:

**Vertex shader**

```
    #version 400 core

    in vec3 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec4 attenuation;

    out vec3 gs_position;
    out vec3 gs_color;
    out vec4 gs_attenuation;

    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
    uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

    void main(void){
        vec4 worldPosition = vec4(position,1.0);
        vec4 viewPosition = viewMatrix * worldPosition;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewPosition;

        gs_position = viewPosition.xyz;
        gs_color = color;
        gs_attenuation = attenuation;
   }
```

**GeometryShader**

```
#version 150

layout (points) in;
layout (triangle_strip,max_vertices = 4) out;

in vec3 gs_position[];
in vec3 gs_color[];
in vec4 gs_attenuation[];


out vec3 fs_position;
out vec3 fs_color;
out vec4 fs_attenuation;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = vec4(-1,1,0,1);
    fs_position = gs_position[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];
    fs_attenuation = gs_attenuation[0];
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(-1,-1,0,1);
    fs_position = gs_position[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];
    fs_attenuation = gs_attenuation[0];
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(1,1,0,1);
    fs_position = gs_position[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];
    fs_attenuation = gs_attenuation[0];
    EmitVertex();

    gl_Position = vec4(1,-1,0,1);
    fs_position = gs_position[0];
    fs_color = gs_color[0];
    fs_attenuation = gs_attenuation[0];
    EmitVertex();

    EndPrimitive();
}
```

**Example of light values:**

- Position: -1, 0.5, -1
- Color: 0, 0.5 ,0
- Attenuation: 1, 0.1, 0.2, 0

As for the requested screenshots, basically without referencing an in variable I get something like this:

[image: Object Normal texture]

And with it I get a black screen, which is pretty easy to visualise.
(Although when rotating the view matrix (y-axis) there is a certain point at which the quad gets colored green, although I cant get values for it)

Comment: OpenGL, wrong tag I see. Removed it

Comment: Obviously the problem is not at this line but that you have undefined behavior somewhere else.

Comment: The gl_PointCoord seems weird, your whole screen is a point ? Didn't you want to use gl_FragCoord ?

Comment: And actually we'd need more code and maybe screenshots to better grasp the problem